# Create 2 cookies in the joomla 1.5 user login

Tags: php, authentication, joomla1.5

i have an issue with a joomla 1.5.26 site this site communicates with external db to handle users and services as well, in order to communicate i have to create 3 cookies, one we can view it in the normal url using the EditThisCookie of chrome in public of the site i have done that using in the index.php using one line of code smthng like that

```
 // create cookie 
 setCookie('cookie_one', 'value_of_cookie_one' , 0, '/', '.mysite.com');
```

Now my problem is that i want in the front end when a registered user logging to create 2 cookies as soon as he/she logging,, one lets say to have the username and a second the session_id of the session

so in the /plugins/user/joomla.php on the function onLoginUser i have added the following code but i get a blank page after the user logging and of course no cookies are seeing using the EditThisCookie of chrome.. my code in the function onLoginUser is like that but i cant figure out were is my mistake... any help would be really appreciated guys...

```
  function onLoginUser($user, $options = array())
{
    $instance =& $this->_getUser($user, $options);
    if ($instance instanceof Exception) {
        return false;
    }
    // If the user is blocked, redirect with an error
    if ($instance->get('block') == 1) {
        return JError::raiseWarning('SOME_ERROR_CODE', JText::_('E_NOLOGIN_BLOCKED'));
    }   
    //Authorise the user based on the group information
    if(!isset($options['group'])) {
        $options['group'] = 'USERS';
    }           
    // Chek the user can login.
    $result = $instance->authorise($options['action']);
    if (!$result) {
        JError::raiseWarning(401, JText::_('JERROR_LOGIN_DENIED'));
        return false;
    }
    //Mark the user as logged in
    $instance->set( 'guest', 0);        
    // Register the needed session variables
    $session =& JFactory::getSession();
    $session->set('user', $instance);       
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();       
    // Check to see the the session already exists.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $app->checkSession();       
    // Update the user related fields for the Joomla sessions table.
    $db->setQuery(
        'UPDATE '.$db->quoteName('#__session') .
        ' SET '.$db->quoteName('guest').' = '.$db->quote($instance->get('guest')).',' .
        '   '.$db->quoteName('username').' = '.$db->quote($instance->get('username')).',' .
        '   '.$db->quoteName('userid').' = '.(int) $instance->get('id') .
        ' WHERE '.$db->quoteName('session_id').' = '.$db->quote($session->getId())
    );
    $db->query();
    // Hit the user last visit field
    $instance->setLastVisit();      
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
//Make sure we are in the frontend
if ($app->isSite())
{   
    // Initialise variables.    
    $url = $this->params->get('url', JURI::base()) . "?currenturl=" . JURI::base();
    $cookie_one = 'value_of_cookie_one';
    $cookie_domain = '.mysite.com';     
    $expire = (time() + 720);
    setCookie('ooo_username', $instance->get('username'), $expire, '/', $cookie_domain);
    setCookie('ooo_municipality_id', $cookie_one, $expire, '/', $cookie_domain);
    setCookie('ooo_session_id', $session->getId(), $expire, '/', $cookie_domain);

    // Tell ME the user is logged in
    if($this->params->get('ooo_redirection', 0) == 1) {
        $app->redirect($url);
    }
}   
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */            
    return true;
}
```

any help would be really appreciated guys thank you!!!!

Comment: Don't use Joomla! 1.5, it's outdated and not supported anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the following before `return true`:

```
    $session = JFactory::getSession();
    $instance =& JFactory::getUser();
    $instance->get('username');
    $cookie_domain = '.mysite.gr';
    $expire = (time() + 720);       
    setCookie('cookie_username', $instance->get('username'), $expire, '/', $cookie_domain);
    setCookie('cookie_session_id', $session->getId(), $expire, '/', $cookie_domain);
```